# Как в случае если убирается повтор символов в строке дополнить её

Tags: python, python-3.x, пароль

У меня есть следующий код:

```
import random
import string

chars = string.digits #Состоит из 10 цифр - 0123456789
number_password = 5 #Количество паролей (спрашивается у пользователя)
length_password = 10 #Длина каждого пароля (спрашивается у пользователя)

for i in range(number_password): #Количество желаемых паролей
                    password = "".join(random.choices(
                        chars,
                        k = length_password #Длина каждого пароля
                    ))
                    list_password = []
                    list_password.append(password)

                    #Убирает повтор с каждого пароля
                    S = set()
                    result = []
                    for i in password:
                            if i in S:
                                continue
                            S.add(i)
                            result.append(i)
                    result_2 = (''.join(map(str, result)))

                    print("Пароль:   ", list_password)
                    print("Без повтора:", result_2)
```

Как видно ниже **"Без повтора"** показал меньше требуемых символов в пароле **(10)**, поэтому мне нужно его как-то дополнить, а если запрашиваемая длина больше, чем есть символов, то сообщить человеку об этом:

```
Пароль:    ['6719841121']
Без повтора: 6719842 
Пароль:    ['3199879159']
Без повтора: 319875
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Сразу получить не повторяющуюся последовательность - `"".join(random.sample(string.digits, length_password))`.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!